# Unable to switch to Advanced View in Search Driven Web Part Query Builder

Tags: content-query-web-part

I've been searching for some time now for some information on how to show the Advanced View of the Query Builder for the Content Search Web Part in SharePoint 2013 On-Prem. I want to sort my search results for any given web part, but every page I read says to simply show the Advanced View of the Query Builder Window. My issue is that I am unable to see the option to switch, and am missing the "Sorting" tab because of it. See this screenshot:

[image: Query Builder missing option to switch to Advanced View]

Can anyone please help me show that option, or explain to me why I'm missing it in the first place? I've seen one (and only one) comment somewhere else on this site about some custom CSS, but I'm unaware of any custom CSS we have on our farm. Any insight offered will be extremely appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: Oh! Apologies for not listing that up-front. We are using 2013 On-Premises

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a Microsoft Service Request for this issue. According to Microsoft, this is a feature, not a bug. There is currently no plan to include the option to "Switch to Advanced Mode" for Query Builder Panels in the Search-Driven Content Web Part Category. I've suggested this feature to be added here:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35541712-enable-switch-to-advanced-mode-on-query-builder-pa